# How to change renderable color/texture within sceneform?

Tags: android, textures, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am building an Android APP that uses AR and for which I am using the sceneform package. I display a 3D model whose ModelRenderable I get by downloading the corresponding .sfb from an external URI. I need for it to be posible to change the model's color when touching a certain button. I have tried a thousand ways without any luck. Is there any simple (or not) way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to set a new material (https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/Renderable#setMaterial(com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Material) when you click the model?

You could also change your Renderable's material. As all instances of a Renderable share the same model instance, so it's a good idea to make a copy before changing a material. Otherwise all other nodes are also affected by the change.

```
val renderableCopy = originalRenderable.makeCopy()
val changedMaterial = renderableCopy.material.makeCopy()
changedMaterial.setFloat3("baseColorTint", Color(android.graphics.Color.rgb(0,255,0)))
renderableCopy.material = changedMaterial
```

Whether you have to change baseColor or baseColorTint depends on your SFA file. Whether the color is set using baseColor or baseColorTint there.

Comment: Hi! The model is a simple .sfb obtained from an obj and an mtl files. Indeed, there are no textures involved, simply color.

Comment: strange, that even if I use makeCopy and successfully change the color, it's gets applied to every object at the scene and not for concrete one =(

Comment: instead cloning the renderable itself worked for me

Comment: @AndreySuvorov I added that step to the source code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can call mtl id from .sfb model as well and pass texture inside it

Comment: can you make an example how to do this?